# How can I make very small quantities of balsamic reduction?

Tags: vinegar, reduction

Last night, a dish called for a drizzle of balsamic reduction. I thought that, in order to get a good reduction and not burn anything, I'd need way more balsamic than the recipe called for.

Is there a way to make very small yields of balsamic reduction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've sometimes made small reductions in the microwave. Just put the liquid in a much deeper container than it fits in so it doesn't make a mess, and run it on 50% power, check every 30 seconds or so until it is reduced to the degree you need.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've made small quantities like that without burning them.  It's easier if you use the smallest pan you have.  Using a smaller pan gets the liquid more to a depth you'd expect from a larger amount in a larger pan.

Comment: Putting a flame tamer under the tiny pan will help, too.

Answer (score 1):

Just speaking generally, why would reducing less liquid be more of an issue if you watch the heat?  It would probably reduce very quickly, like in 2-3 minutes on low-medium heat.